# Invalid Endblock tag in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am receiving an error message when I go to one of my pages in my Django project, as it is saying that the End-block tag is invalid (asks whether I remembered to register or load). The error looks like this:
[image]
My code for this template - (login.html) - is below:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.'</p>
    {% endif %}

    <form method="post" action="{% url 'users:login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <button name="sumbit">log in</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% extends 'learning_logs/index.html' %}" />
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

I am very confused, and I am wondering whether anyone knows what the problem is?
Thanks
Milo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% extends 'learning_logs/index.html' %}" />
```

Above line contains `{% extends .... %}`. To prevent being interpreted as a `extends` tag, use [`templatetag` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag):

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% templatetag openblock %} extends 'learning_logs/index.html' {% templatetag closeblock %}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use `{% endblock %}` instead o f `{% endblock content %}`

Comment: According to the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance): "For extra readability, you can optionally give a name to your endblock" and the latest linter rules encourages it.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was wrongly auto-formatted html file. Check auto-formatting for html files.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32358585)

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas why it is not an answer to the question? If I would find this answer, that would be an answer in my case. If you dont understand the context and need clarification that always can be and its ok to ask for clarification, again for me it would not need further clarification.